# How to insert new row for each record in a table?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I would like to insert a row of interest for each customer at the end of each month only after checking for the same.
It is working for the first one but not for the rest. I'm clueless how to use 'For..each' here... :|

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Dim Str(0) As String
    Str(0) = GetID("Transactions", "ID")
    Dim TempStr(5) As String

    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Com.CommandText = "Select * From Customer"
        Dr = Com.ExecuteReader
        While Dr.Read()
            TempStr(0) = Dr(0).ToString
            TempStr(1) = Dr(2).ToString
            TempStr(2) = Dr(3).ToString
            TempStr(3) = Dr(5).ToString
            TempStr(4) = Dr(6).ToString
            TempStr(5) = Dr(7).ToString

            Dim LastIntDate = DateAdd("m", 0, DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), 0))
            Try
                Com.CommandText = "Select * From Transactions WHERE CID=" & TempStr(0).ToString & " AND TDate=#" & LastIntDate & "# AND Description='Interest'"
                Dr2 = Com.ExecuteReader
                If Dr2.Read = True Then
                    Dr2.Close()
                Else
                    Try
                        Com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transactions Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                        With Com.Parameters
                            .Add("@ID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Str(0).ToString
                            .Add("@CustID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TempStr(0).ToString
                            .Add("@TDate", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today
                            .Add("@Credit", OleDb.OleDbType.Currency).Value = 0
                            .Add("@Debit", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 500
                            .Add("@Balance", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Val(TempStr(3) + Interest)
                            .Add("@Desc", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Interest"
                        End With
                        Com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        Com.Parameters.Clear()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.Message)
                    End Try

                    Try
                        Com.CommandText = "Update Customer Set CurrBal=? WHERE ID=?"
                        With Com.Parameters
                            .Add("@CurrBal", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = (TempStr(3) + Interest)
                            .Add("@CustID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TempStr(0).ToString
                        End With
                        Com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        Com.Parameters.Clear()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End If
                Dr2.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End While
        Dr.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are close. You don't want to `Dr.Read` while false, you want to read while true. Typically it is just:</s>

```
Do While Dr.Read()
```

ok, I think you are doing too much work, you are not using proper Dispose pattern and you are using sql injection vulnerable implementation, but to answer your question:

The reason it only works for the first customer is that you only read the first record from `Dr`. Bad practices aside, do something like this:

```
Dim Str(0) As String
Str(0) = GetID("Transactions", "ID")
Dim TempStr(5) As String

Try
    Conn.Open()
    Com.CommandText = "Select * From Customer"
    Dr = Com.ExecuteReader
    While Dr.Read()
        TempStr(0) = Dr(0).ToString
        TempStr(1) = Dr(2).ToString
        TempStr(2) = Dr(3).ToString
        TempStr(3) = Dr(5).ToString
        TempStr(4) = Dr(6).ToString
        TempStr(5) = Dr(7).ToString

        '**********************
        ' All your other stuff goes here so that it executes once
        ' for each customer
        '**********************            
    End While
    Dr.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Actually I don't have to find that, that's why used Dr.read = False. If it doesn't have that already, only then the interest should be posted.

Comment: Then you would be better off checking `Dr.HasRows` than seeing if the first read returns false.

Comment: You could save even more trouble by doing `INSERT INTO [Transactions].. blah bah.. WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...where cid =, etc.`. This would eliminate the first command and the loop.

Comment: Can you show me an example for Dr.Hasrows to check all records one by one nd then insert the row(s) ? WHERE NOT EXISTS didn't worked, doing same as earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I've updated my codes but still no luck. Now its not inserting a single row rather than giving me an error msg. : "There is already an open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first." I had tried to use two different DR, i.e. DR & DR2. Please check my first post.

Comment: I removed a call to Close() in my answer. You will have to rework it a bit, probably create a second datareader instead of reusing the same one within the while loop. I'm on my phone right now so I can't give exact implementation.

Comment: Ohh.. Ok, I did close the one I had implemented. Please check whenever you'll have some free time.. I tried whatever I was aware of but no luck. Also, can we talk on Skype or any other ? Don't worry, I won't disturb you.